# Can I use pandas read_csv converter conditionally?

Tags: python, pandas

I was wondering whether it is possible to use a converter conditionally based on the type of a column. For example if your dataset consists of two columns where the first one can be either an integer or timestamp it would be nice to be able to use a converter conditionally if the file eventually has a timestamp column and avoid calling the converter if the column has integer values.

This can be done outside of the `read_csv` when the data are already loaded but it's probably going to be less efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [read_csv docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) state that you can pass a custom date parsing function using the `date_parser` argument.

So you could do something like:

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
from dateutil.parser import parse


def parse_date_or_ts(data):
    try:
        return parse(data)
    except ValueError:
        # let's assume data is a utc timestamp now
        return datetime.utcfromtimestamp(int(data))

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv',
                 parse_dates={'date': [0]},  # index 0 is our date/ts mixed column
                 date_parser=parse_date_or_ts)
```

Comment: I ended up pushing the condition inside the converter, so my solution is very similar to this except that I don't explicitly use a date parser. Btw I avoided using a try catch statement, although it is more intuitive, because for the cases where an exception was raised, probably due to the asynchronous nature of exception handling, it impacted the performance badly. So instead I used a dummy / hackish condition like `if len(data.split(':'))>1:`. Which I hate but it is faster.

Comment: You're right, in terms of execution time, try except isn't the fastest way to do it. I just used it as an example. But if your timestamp is only made if digits, you can also use [str.isdigit()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit), which is more readable and should be very fast.

Comment: So I assume there is no way to avoid calling the converter / date_parser, hence the answer to my question should be no, right?

Comment: No, I don't think there is a better solution than using a custom parser if you don't know what the column data will look like in advance.

Comment: Do you think I should mark the question as answered? I tried to edit your answer so as to include a conclusion like "No, but you can do that" in the beginning of your answer, but it was rejected.